# Monthly sentinel-2 Max and Mean NDVI, and B9 values extracted to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, sentinel-2

When trying to run this code I get an error:

> Expected Type: Image(unknown bands) actual type:ImageCollections

I would also like to maintain the ID column to be the ID column in my shapefile(labelled "Table")
geometry: AOI
table: shapefile with many polygons, want to extract by each polygon

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED');

//Sentinel -1 seasonal images

var s2April = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-04-01', '2020-4-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2May = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-05-01', '2020-05-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2June = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-06-01', '2020-06-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2July =s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2August = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-08-01', '2020-08-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2September = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-09-01', '2020-09-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

var s2October = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-10-01', '2020-10-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));
  
var s2November = s2
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-11-01', '2020-11-25'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}
//NDVI: image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
//GRVI: image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B4']).rename('grvi')
//GBVI: image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B3']).rename('gbvi')
//NDMI: image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B11']).rename('ndmi')
// Map the function over the collection

var april = s2April.map(addNDVI);
var may = s2May.map(addNDVI);
var june = s2June.map(addNDVI);
var july = s2July.map(addNDVI);
var august = s2August.map(addNDVI);
var september = s2September.map(addNDVI);
var october = s2October.map(addNDVI);
var november = s2November.map(addNDVI);


Map.centerObject(geometry);


//add optical map layers
Map.addLayer(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry,{color:"blue"});

//create collection of S1 values
var Change = ee.Image.cat(
        april,
        may,
        june,
        july,
        august,
        september,
        october,
        november);
//export to table
//export to table
var s2Means = Change.reduceRegions({
  collection: table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10
});
//ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['export'])
print(s2Means);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:s2Means,
  description:'Region_MonthlyMeanNDVI',
  fileFormat:'csv',
})
```

I want to do this for NDVI and other indices, but also bands: 9 and 10. All as separate tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with concatinating images. You need to select images while you are providing image collections for the 'Change' variable. Now you have to select the monthly mean NDVI for all the images of a certain month. Then you can add them as a band to create a new image. You can select a particular band e.g. 'ndvi' and rename it with the month. Otherwise, it can be hard to identify the period of ndvi. Similarly you can do for other indices and bands by modifying the `select()` parameter and renaming it.

```
var Change_NDVI = ee.Image.cat(
        [april.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_April'),
        may.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_may'),
        june.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_june'),
        july.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_july'),
        august.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_august'),
        september.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_september'),
        october.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_october'),
        november.select('ndvi').mean().rename('ndvi_november')]);
//export to table
var s2Means = Change_NDVI.reduceRegions({
  collection: table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10
  })

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:s2Means,
  description:'Region_MonthlyMeanNDVI',
  fileFormat:'csv',
})
```

Comment: beautiful. thank you for your help. This worked very well